# how to change the output file format in pSQL from default to csv?

Tags: psql

I am using Linux and has connected to a pSQL DB server. After using the command \o to export file, the output file is separated by "|" horizontally and "_" (and '+') vertically. Please see below:

```
abc | cde | fgh | xyz
----+-----+-----+-----
123 | 321 | 123 | 123
123 | 321 | 222 | 111
923 | 238 | 928 | 192
```

ect.

This format might be a default but not very useful for data analysis.

Can I change the output file format into ".csv" by some additional optional command in pSQL?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export CSV in psql. There's a dedicated command to do so. I've written a longer [article](https://phili.pe/posts/exporting-csv-from-postgresql/) on this.

The gist is this:

```
\copy (SELECT ...) TO 'locale_file.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER)
```

This will copy the data as CSV to your local drive (i.e. where psql is running from).